# OSX Swift cannot assign value of type string to type NSTextFieldCell

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

Hi I want to make a timer to shutdown my mac, I have this code :

```
@IBOutlet weak var valueofSlider: NSTextFieldCell! //label textfield

@IBAction func valueChange(sender: NSSlider) {
    var x :Double = sender.doubleValue
    valueofSlider = "x"
}
```

But I got the following error :

> cannot assign value of type String to type NSTextFieldCell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is `valueOfSlider`? The error you are getting suggests that it's an NSTextFieldCell.

You should hook your outlet to the text field, not the text field cell.

The code would be something like this:

```
myTextField.stringValue = "\(x)"
```

Or better yet

```
myTextField.stringValue = String(format: "%.1f", x)
```

Comment: valueofSlider is the name of my label. I try your code thanks

Comment: now i can launch the programm but the value of the label don't change ... http://imgur.com/73CPQwk

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 @IBAction func valueChange(sender: NSSlider) {
var x :Double = sender.doubleValue
valueofSlider = "\(x)"
 }
```